# Issue with downloading the file from Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, file, sharepoint, download, xlsx

I am using the below code to download a xlsx file from Sharepoint. The file gets downloaded and shows as xlsx file but it fails to open as it gives the error [image: Error when opening the xlsx file]

I believe it is because it is in binary format probably which is why this error is showing up but not totally sure. Can anyone please advise how to download the xlsx file such that it can be opened as it is in xlsx format itself?

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import urllib.request
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth


ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext('url')
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user('username', 'password')   
ctx = ClientContext('url', ctx_auth)
response = File.open_binary(ctx, "/Documents/file.xlsx")
with open("./file.xlsx", "wb") as local_file:
   local_file.write(response.content)
```

The code actually works to download a xlsx file. But the downloaded file dosent opens up and gives error.